# Event Handler for Accept Button in WinRT Date Picker

Tags: datepicker, event-handling, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am looking for a way to perform some actions when the user taps the accept/checkmark button in the `DatePicker` control **also when the user does not change the date**, i.e. this should be different from canceling out of the `DatePicker` by tapping the back or cancel button. Is there a way to add an event handler to this button?

[image]

Background: to help the user selecting a recent date (and avoid excessive scrolling), the `DatePicker` is set to today's date. The user should be able to

1. select another date and tap the accept button -> date is saved (this I can handle in the `DateChanged` event) -> OK (sort of)
2. cancel by tapping the back or cancel button -> assumed the user does not want to set a date, and no action to save (no event handler needed) -> OK
3. select the suggested date (today) by tapping the accept button -> date is supposed to be saved but `DateChanged` does not fire and there is no event for the accept button tapped.

Given the initial answer below I should perhaps emphasize that this is not about getting the date value from the control but about **knowing if the user has tapped the accept/checkmark button or canceled the selection**. What I'm looking for is a way to customize the `DatePicker` control so that allows me to capture that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior, the ***DateChanged*** event is fired only when the date actually change.

Of course you still have a way to have the selected date. Give a name to your DatePicker element:

```
<DatePicker Name="DatePick" Height="47" Width="323"/>
```

Then you can get the date by looking at the Date property:

```
DateTimeOffset selectedDate = DatePick.Date;
```

Those 2 buttons (done / cancel) are just there to validate the changes made in this UI:

- Done : change the value of the Date in the DatePicker element, if the date was changed the DateChanged event is fired, if not then nothing happen.
- Cancel (or backbutton) : cancel the date selection, the Date property of the DatePicker element stay the same even if you changed the selected date in the DatePicker.

If you want to know if the user accepted the date you show him, don't use the buttons in the DatePicker UI but add two buttons on your own page, the buttons in the DatePicker UI are just to validate or cancel a change you made to the date.

Comment: Thank you. That's understood. But how do I know whether the user has accepted the "suggested" date by tapping the checkmark button or canceled the date selection by tapping the back or the cancel button?

Comment: @jery That is not possible